# Josephson Potential Derivations

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, superconductivity, josephson-junction

I am currently reading the [following](https://cmx-jc.mit.edu/sites/default/files/documents/quantumPhaseSlipNotes.pdf) lecture notes to understand phase slips in the Josephson junction (JJ). For now, I am trying to understand how to derive the Josephson potential. I am first given the two Josephson equations for an ideal Josephson junction, which are the following:

$$ I = I_C \sin \gamma $$

$$ \frac{d\gamma}{dt} = \frac{2eV}{\hbar} $$

Here, $\gamma$ is the phase difference of the superconductors across the junction. The lecture notes mention that

> > The equation $I = I_c \sin \gamma$ is, in fact, only applicable in a particular limit: $I < I_c$
> > . When $I$ exceeds $I_c$, $\gamma$ is a function of time and we now have a finite voltage across the junction. We will need amore sophisticated model to proceed.... We can imagine modeling the JJ as one pure JJ element described by the two essential equations above along with a capacitor C and resistor R in parallel, effectively shunting the junction as depicted in Fig. 2.

The lecture notes then derives a second order differential equation for $\gamma$ from Kirchof's laws and determine the Josephson potential. I understand the mathematics; however, I do not understand why figure 2 shows the RCSJ model and four cases of $I$: $I = 0$, $0 < I < T_C$, $I \approx I_C$ and $I >> I_C$. Isn't the circuit model only valid when $I > I_C$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the RCSJ circuit model as in your lecture notes

$$\frac{d^2\gamma }{d\tau^2}+\frac{1}{Q}\frac{d\gamma}{d\tau}+\sin{\gamma}=\frac{I}{I_c}$$
when $I<I_c$ the RHS is less than $1$ and thus a time-constant phase $\sin \gamma = I/I_c$ is a solution for this differential equation. Therefore the equation agrees with the first Josephson relation when $I<I_c$ and there is no need to separate cases.